# How to remove x axis labels in R cdplot?

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, density-plot

I would like to remove the default x-axis labels provided by cdplot, and then use the axis() function to introduce my custom labels.

## Example

```
Forest = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1)
change = c(-1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 6)
mydata = data.frame(Forest,change)

x = factor(mydata$Forest)

cdplot(x~mydata$change, ylab = NA, xlab = NA)
```

The command `xaxt="n"` does not work with the cdplot function, while `xaxlabels = "n"` does not exist at all.

I also tried to use `par(xaxt="n")` to setup the graphic parameters ex ante, but then prompting the `axis(1,...)` command does not produce any effect.

Can anyone shed some light about how to procede?

Thanks

Comment: `Forest = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1) change = c(-1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 6) mydata = data.frame(Forest,change) x = factor(mydata$Forest) cdplot(x~mydata$change, ylab = NA, xlab = "type what you want")` it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried turning off the axis, plotting, then turning them back on?

```
par(xaxt="n")
cdplot(x~mydata$change, ylab = NA, xlab = NA)
par(xaxt="s")
axis(1, ...)
```

Comment: I tried something similar but did use xaxt="s" specificly. It worked fine. Thank you very much!